Javascript - Elements added into an array not in correct place
I have a little problem to add some element in place into an array. I'm trying to add after the last lowercase letter that is z the uppercase letter of the alphabet. I'm using this code. I've noticed that the lower char z is added after all the uppercase letters are added into the array, also the first two uppercase letters are repeated before the lower z is added. How I can fix this?
onst splitMatrix = async (inputMatrix: string) => {
  let splitted: Array<string> = inputMatrix.split(''); 
  let index: number = splitted.indexOf("z");
  //let uppercaseChars: Array<string> = [];
  //
  index + 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < 23;i++){
    let char: string = splitted[i].toUpperCase();
    //uppercaseChars.push(char);
    splitted.splice(index + i, 0, char);
    console.log(char)
  }
  //console.log(uppercaseChars)
  //console.log(splitted)
  return splitted;
}

This is what I will have as result of the code
[
  'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i',
  'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't',
  'u', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E',
  'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',
  'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'A',
  'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
  '8', '9', '@', '-', '_', '+', '*', '(', ')',
  ',', '.', '#'
]

My idea is to add a control on the chars to avoid duplicated entries into the array, but I'm open to any tips to solve this. Thank you

Please [edit] the code here to be a [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to work on it. Right now this is just a function (well, almost, you've written onst instead of const) and you're not calling it. You should show code that runs the function, and what output you're expecting (not just a verbal description of it; I'm having a hard time understanding your description; a concrete input/output example would be much clearer).

Iterate the array, stop at the original length (len), and push the uppercased letters to the end:


const splitMatrix = inputMatrix => {
  const splitted = inputMatrix.split(''); 
  
  const len = splitted.length;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++){
    splitted.push(splitted[i].toUpperCase());
  }

  return splitted;
}

const result = splitMatrix('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');

console.log(result);



Another option is to map the lowercase characters array to an array of uppercase letters, and then concat it with the lowercase array:


const splitMatrix = inputMatrix => {
  const lowerCase = inputMatrix.split(''); 
  
  return lowerCase.concat(
    lowerCase.map(l => l.toUpperCase())
  );
}

const result = splitMatrix('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');

console.log(result);




I like the solution you've suggested. I will need to adapt it to have the uppercase letters after the last lowercase that is at the index position 22, but this is only to have all letters before the numbers and other chars

I guess this code will help you. It will work even if your last lowercase is not z. It finds first non-lowercase char, then uppercases all of chars before:
const findFirstNonLowercaseIndex = (input: string) => {
    let i = 0;
    while (i < input.length) {
        const char = input[i];
        const isLowercase = /[a-z]/.test(char);
        if (!isLowercase) return i;
        i++;
    }
    return i;
};

const splitMatrix = (input: string) => {
    const firstNonLowercaseIndex = findFirstNonLowercaseIndex(input);
    const previousPart = input.slice(0, firstNonLowercaseIndex);
    const restPart = input.slice(firstNonLowercaseIndex);
    const uppedPreviousPart = previousPart.toUpperCase();
    return `${previousPart}${uppedPreviousPart}${restPart}`.split("");
};


